# The best way to collect data from multiple components into one in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am relatively new to Angular, and I understand my question might be very primitive, but please advice me the best solution in my case.

I have a Stepper (from Angular Material); the contents of each step are inside different components; in all the steps we collect data from a customer using multiple input fields.

The code looks like below.

Stepper:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="stepOne">
    <ng-template matStepLabel><span class="someClass">Customer Information</span></ng-template>

    <step-one></-step-one>

  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="stepTwo">
    <ng-template matStepLabel><span class="someClass">Payment Information</span></ng-template>

    <step-two></step-two>

  </mat-step>
    ...
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel><span class="someClass">Confirmation</span></ng-template>

    <confirmation></confirmation>

  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Contents (lots of fields like this):

```
  <mat-form-field class="dcp-input-field">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="name" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
      ...
  </mat-form-field>
```

What I want, is to collect all the data in the last "confirmation" controller, to show it to the customer. I know there are various ways of communication between components, but which one is the best in this case?
I've tried using service, but something went wrong.

Please just send me a link to any reference that can answer my question, it should be enough.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You could have an array into a servie. A simple `public config: any[] = [];` and each step you do you push your custom data. When the `<confirmation>` is rendered you simply take the value of the array and you got the data you need. Or also you could use `viewChild` to get the single component value when needed (This request the single components to be part of the main one)

Comment: Do you have a parent (steper component) and in it the child components (each one is a step) ?

Comment: Yes, the stepper is a parent component with child and grand-child components inside it

Answer (score 2):

A service is not the correct solution in your case.

You should have the data object in parent component and pass it as an [input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) to all child components (steps).

**Edit**:

Sample code:

**Parent**:

Define the data object in the parent Component:

```
data = {};
```

Pass data object to step-one child component in parent template:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="stepOne">
    <ng-template matStepLabel><span class="someClass">Customer Information</span></ng-template>
    <step-one [data]="data"></-step-one>
  </mat-step>
  ...
```

**Child**:

Define the @Input data object to receive from parent:

```
@Input() data: {};
```

**Summary**: This way, all children will work with the parent's data object, and once submitted in parent component, the data is there.

Comment: But doesn't he want the exact opposite. In his Question he states that the inputs are in components. He would need Ouput Bindings for that and only on the last step if he uses a Component there a input binding @benshabatnoam

Comment: @Nikolai Kiefer, Andrew needs all child component's data to be collected to one single place where he could have a reference to it, in this case having the data in the parent component is the most logical thing to do. In other words, the child components job is to collect the data and the parent's job is to do something with the collected data. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a service that holds variables for you, on each step you set the variables within the service to the data you need to hold. Then when you complete your stepper all the data within the service will be ready and waiting.

here are the Angular docs for this. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

With that service, set up a function that returns all the data you need in the order you require, and subscribe to it with the final step, as seen here. 
 [Subscriptions](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)

Then you should have all of your data when you need it at the end of the stepper.

Just remember that when you have finished using your data to clear all the variables held within the service to avoid any issues with the stepper returning the wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using `viewChild` you can act this way:

First child component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp-1',
  template: ''
})
export class Cmp1Component  {
  public data: any[] = [
    {
      name: "component 1",
      action: "something",
      status: "alive"
    }
  ]
}
```

Second child component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp-2',
  template: ''
})
export class Cmp2Component  {
  public data: any[] = [
    {
      name: "component 2",
      action: "something else",
      status: "not alive"
    }
  ]
}
```

Main component the use `ViewChildren` to get data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('cmp1') component1: Cmp1Component;
  @ViewChild('cmp2') component2: Cmp2Component;
}
```

the related html and css

```
<cmp-1 #cmp1></cmp-1>
<cmp-2 #cmp2></cmp-2>

<h1>Here's the data from the components</h1>

<hr>

<h3>Component 1</h3>

<div class="box">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let data of component1.data">
    <div>{{data.name}}</div>
    <div>{{data.action}}</div>
    <div>{{data.status}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h3>Component 2</h3>

<div class="box">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let data of component2.data">
    <div>{{data.name}}</div>
    <div>{{data.action}}</div>
    <div>{{data.status}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**NOTE** I haven't checked if both of component exists, in this example, because I know it for sure since it's just all in a static context. Be sure to check them if you eneded before doing some logic.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1tunk

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that i know and would recommend.

1. Your Stepper is in the Parent Component and every Step has a child-omponent with an Output-binding. You parent gets the change on those variables [component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)
2. A service which each child Component sends it data to and where your building your array/object. Then later send it from the service to the parent.

i would recommend the first solution with output-bindings