# pass data between components in angular that all have the same parent route

Tags: angular

I have a route like this:

```
export const UploadsRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: UrlPaths.uploads,
    component: UploadsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UploadsListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: FileUploadComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want don't want to have to observe the same properties in each component.  If They all existed in a template then I could pass them as props.

I could create an injectable service but then I have to use observers in every component and observe on the service.

That does not seem much better than just having them each component.

Is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to collect data from multiple components into one in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608380/the-best-way-to-collect-data-from-multiple-components-into-one-in-angular-6)

Comment: @dagda1 use `QueryParams`

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, an injectable service that you subscribe to in each component would be the best solution.

Comment: can I avoid all the observing.  Seems nuts

Comment: @dagda1 Observables would be the best way to go, if done correctly they are quite nice to work with

Comment: what I mean is if I am observing the same observables in the same service in different components then it seems no different than having to observe them separately in each component

Comment: @dagda1 It seems a bit tedious but is the least tedious and hacky of all your options unfortuntaly. You can just use a variable in a shared service as opposed to an observable if you don't need to listen for the event and just want to pass the data and use it manually